# About copying files into Pendrive

Tags: gnome, 20.04

when i paste the copied file in my pendrive it starts copying with a high speed(60 mb/s) and completes 75% of file and the speed of copying gradually decreases and it reaches 9.1 mb/s and it takes more time to copy remaining 15% of file and it hangs at **0 seconds left ** and it never  show file copied even i wait for a long time.

Comment: As i am new to ubuntu please help me to find out this problem

Comment: You said you are new to Ubuntu, Ubuntu 20.04 is not too much stable compare to Ubuntu 18.04 or 16.04, specially for beginners, consider using 18.04 or 16.04.

Comment: Usually the write speed of the pendrive's memory cells is limiting the speed. The reason why the copy process seems fast in the beginning is that the written data are buffered in RAM. But when no more data will be allowed to be buffered you have to wait for the data to be written to the USB memory cells. -- If you have written many times to the pendrive, it will get slower. Then it may help to wipe the whole device (overwrite it with zeros). You can do that with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb).

Answer (score 2):

I doubt using an earlier version of Ubuntu would help too much as the same happens with Zorin 15, it's more likely to do with how exFAT and FAT32 volumes are handled. Here's a solution that works for me from github:

If you are running a x64 bit Ubuntu or other Linux and find USB transfers hang at the end apply this fix:

```
echo $((16*1024*1024)) > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_bytes
echo $((48*1024*1024)) > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes
```

I suggest you edit your `/etc/rc.local` file to make this change persistant across reboots.

`sudo nano /etc/rc.local`

Go to the bottom of the file and leave a space then paste in those two lines.

Save the file with ctrl + x then press y.

To revert the changes enter this in console and remove the lines in `/etc/rc.local`

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_bytes
echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes
```

More info and references: 
https://gist.github.com/2E0PGS/f63544f8abe69acc5caaa54f56efe52f
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107703/why-is-my-pc-freezing-while-im-copying-a-file-to-a-pendrive/107722#107722